# If a vector field with zero divergence vanishes on a flat portion of boundary, its normal derivative is zero

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let's consider a vector field $v$ in a bounded region $R$ of the space; assume that $\operatorname{div}v=0$ and $v=0\,\,\text{on}\,\, \partial R$; I have to prove that $$(\nabla v)^Tn=0$$
where $n$ is the outward unit normal to $\partial R$, for a plane portion of boundary.
I have evaluated $(\nabla v)^Tn$ and I get $\nabla v_3$ ($v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$).
I don't succeed in proving it is zero; any suggestion?
I have also tried to use the divergence theorem but then I have problems to localize the result.

Comment: Suppose the plane portion of the boundary is $x_3=0$. Calculate $\operatorname{div}v$ at the boundary points, and you'll see it is exactly $(\nabla v)^Tn$.

Comment: I'm not understanding; the divergence is a scalar and $(\nabla v)^tn$ is a vector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the plane is $x_3=0$; this appears to be your assumption too. For the points in the plane, 
$$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} =0,\qquad i=1,2,3,\quad j=1,2$$
because all components are zero along the $x_1$ and $x_2$ directions.

Hence, the divergence of $v$ (which is zero by assumption) is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_3}$$
This completes the proof of $\nabla v_3=0$.